# PHP - how to increase maximum filesize/lines in file?

Tags: php, ssh, stream, output, max

I have written a script that parse an output from the stream:

```
stream_set_blocking($result, true);
$res = stream_get_contents($result);
```

then, later in script I am saving the result of the stream to the file

```
 fwrite($file,$res);
```

It works pretty well for small files but when the output stream sends lets say 50k lines of text then it saves about 4098 lines in file:

```
wc -l for file from which I will read the output stream: 62565
wc -l for file saved on final location: 4098
```

I have checked the memory_limit for php and it is 128M:

```
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
```

Notes:

```
files are on two separate machines and I am connecting by ssh2_connect php function
60k of lines => ~10 MB of text
```

EDIT:
Just found an workaround:

```
$chunks = str_split($res, 922900);
$iterate = 0;
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    file_put_contents($file, $chunk, FILE_APPEND);
    $iterate++;
}
```

Has anyone got any clue how to fix that in more proper way?

Comment: is it `fwrite($file,$result);` or `fwrite($file,$res);` ?

Comment: It is $res, edited it, thanks. Tried to fix that with file_put_contents but it works in the same way (the same amount of lines in file)

Comment: Can you check `$res` contents length with `mb_strlen` for example?

Comment: Yeah the mb_strlen of $res is `14144181`

Comment: OK, and what is the original file size? and what is the newly written filesize? `14144181` seems to be the original file size.

Comment: The original one: 14M
The new one: 902K

Comment: I suggest you to keep writing to the file, until the whole string is written to it. Use the [following snippet](http://pastebin.com/ZMSaUiJV) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly it is not working in that way.

Comment: Any error? Warning? ...

Comment: Nah, there is no error nor warning, it just outputs the same file like in the first methods.

Comment: What are your php `display_errors` and `error_reporting` setting values?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);`